# Setting Bootstraps Popover to 'click' or 'manual' from 'hover.'

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been working on embedding an interactive element (a search function) within bootstrap's popover. I haven't been able to test it's functionality because I can't seem to, just as importantly, set the event either in javascript or markup to 'click' rather than 'hover.' I'm a js neophyte, so do bear with me.

```
<div class="popover-markup"> <a href="#" class="trigger">Search</a>
    <div class="head hide">Find an Action</div>
    <div class="content hide">
        <input class='input-block-level' id='search_address' placeholder='Enter an address or an intersection' type='text'>
        <select class='input-small' id='search_radius'>
            <option value='400'>2 blocks</option>
            <option value='805'>1/2 mile</option>
            <option value='1610'>1 mile</option>
            <option value='3220'>2 miles</option>
        </select>
         <h4>Find a School or Campus</h4>
        <input class='input-block-level' id='text_search' placeholder="Find a School or Campus" type='text' data-provide="typeahead">
        <input class='btn btn-primary' id='search' type='button' value='Search'>
        <button class='btn' id='reset'>Reset</button>
    </div>
    <div class="footer hide">test</div>
```

and here is the js:

```
$('.popover-markup>.trigger').popover({ 
    html : true,
    title: function() {
        return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
    },
    content: function() {
        return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to add the proper trigger:
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers

```
$('.popover-markup>.trigger').popover({ 
            html : true,
        --> trigger: 'hover',
            title: function() {
            return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
            },
            content: function() {
            return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
            }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks, Brandon. I realized 'hover' is a string, as well.